# Can't able to get subjects in multidimentional array

Tags: php

```
$student = array();
$subjects = array();
foreach($this->items as $std)
{
    foreach($this->items as $course)
    {
        $subjects[$course->course_title] = $course->obtain_marks;
    }
    $student[$std->std_id]  = array($std->std_id, $std->name,$subjects);
   }
```

output: Its showing me the same subject result and not picking the result of first student please help...........the output is given below.............

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => ayan
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [english] => 43
                    [urdu] => 55
                    [IQ] => 25
                    [OP] => 15
                    [nazra] => 15
                    [G.K] => 15
                    [maths] => 70
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => bilal
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [english] => 43
                    [urdu] => 55
                    [IQ] => 25
                    [OP] => 15
                    [nazra] => 15
                    [G.K] => 15
                    [maths] => 70
                )

        )

)
```

how can i get both results................

Comment: what is in the object ? and why are you usinf a foreach in a foreach whithout using data from the first foreach ?!?!? and the most important... what is your goal ?

Comment: i want to get subjects as key and marks as values so i have created two dimensional array bt it is not getting the result of first student its getting the result of second student only

Comment: just like i sayed... the foreach is kinda sinceless... check the post of Jay Bhatt, it's the same i was talking about and might solve the problem

Comment: it would help us if you would post some data from your `$this->items` object

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted much context and since your using nested loops I assume your trying to get the value from a sub array. Based on this you have a problem in your foreach loop. It should be something like below.

```
foreach($this->items as $std)
{
    foreach($std as $course) //It should be $std here instead of $this->items.
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: $student = array();
$subjects = array();
foreach($this->items as $std)
  {
    $subjects[$std->std_id][$std->course_title] =  $std->obtain_marks;
    $student[$std->std_id]  = array($std->std_id, $std->name,$subjects[$std->std_id]);
   }

Comment: i got the answer thnx for ur help

Comment: @UzairAhmad do you see the Zero at the top left of this post ? propably there is a hook too. Both can be used to say: `this post was helpful` please use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

change the result array key value

```
foreach($this->items as $std)
{
    foreach($coursearray as $course)
    {
        $subjects[$course->course_title] = $course->obtain_marks;
    }
    $student[]  = array('standard_id'=>$std->std_id,'standard_name'=>$std->name,'subjects'=>$subjects);
   }
```

Comment: ? whats is the difference to his post? only difference is that you use names instead of numbers....

Comment: man he told the first student record missing   $student[here i emptied]

Comment: you can't get other results with `$this->items as $std` and `$this->items as $course`

Comment: he also did the same . i dont know the sturucture of object he used here. i figure out the problem here there are two arrays may be used here .just assume . unless how can get this result array he displayed . ask to him for a clarification .its unclear on this question

Comment: @Dwza **not picking the result of first student please help** this what he ask?

Answer (score 0):

leaning to my comment and also to Jay Bhatt's post....

here you have to see if your object contains arrays

```
$student = array();
$subjects = array();

foreach($this->items as $std)
{
    foreach($std as $course) //It should be $std here instead of $this->items.
    {
        $subjects[$course['course_title'] = $course['obtain_marks'];
    }
    $student[$std->std_id]  = array($std->std_id, $std->name, $subjects);
}
```

or subObjects

```
$student = array();
$subjects = array();

foreach($this->items as $std)
{
    foreach($std as $course) //It should be $std here instead of $this->items.
    {
        $subjects[$course->course_title] = $course->obtain_marks;
    }
    $student[$std->std_id]  = array($std->std_id, $std->name, $subjects);
}
```